# PHP - Mysql - display data

Tags: php

I'm starting to play with PHP and MySQL.

However, I have encountered a problem and can not deal with it.

In my database I have data such as: id, domain_name, year, month, organic_search_visit

I want to display them now using PHP, but the data is displayed not as I want.

The data in my database looks like this:

Site1.com
January - 2017 - 11k visit
February - 2017 - 10k visit
...
January - 2018 - 11k visit
February - 2018 - 10k visit
...

Site2.com
January - 2017 - 11k visit
February - 2017 - 10k visit
...
January - 2018 - 11k visit
February - 2018 - 10k visit
...

I want to display the data from the database using PHP in the table so that it can see how I had traffic in a given year / month.

[image: Table - site1.com]
[image: Table - site2.com]

My code:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT domain_name, month, year, organic_search_visit FROM organic_search");

echo "<table>";
echo "<thead><tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo "<td>Month</td>";
    echo "<th>".''.$row['month'].''."</th>";
    echo "</tr><thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>2017</td>";
    echo "<td>".''.$row['organic_search_visit'].''."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: and what's the problem exactly? What do you get now from your code? What did you expect?

Comment: You have two `<thead>` and no `</thead>` in your code. Also, shouldn't the hardcoded `2017` be replaced by `$row['year']`?

Comment: You probably need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns both numerical and named array keys (`MYSQLI_BOTH` is default)

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($results)` and `$results->fetch_array()` should be equivalent

Comment: I think the problem is how to pivot table tabulate and display the data.

Comment: I also have the impression that the problem is with the table itself.

The data from the database is all that he wants, he wants to present it in the table now.

I threw you this code because maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with sorted result data. Iterate through the data and print the relevant table and row tags when they change in the data.

You can use something like the example below. Note that this has a fixed list of months for column headers and requires the data to match.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT domain_name, month, year, organic_search_visit FROM organic_search GROUP BY domain_name,month,year, ORDER BY domain_name, year, month");
$months = array('January', 'February', 'March'); //etc
$domain = "";
$year = "";
$month = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    if($domain!=$row['domain_name']){ //Check if the domain has changed
        $domain = $row['domain_name'];
        $year = "";
        $month = 0;
        if($domain!="") echo "</tr></table>"; //Only close last domain table if there was a previous domain
        echo "<table><tr><th>".$domain."</th>"; //Start new domain table
        foreach($months as $month) echo "<td>".$month."</td>"; //Print header row
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if($year!=$row['year']){
        $year = $row['year'];
        $month = 0;
        if($year!="") echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$year."</td>";
    }
    while($months[$month] != $row['month']){
        $month+=1;
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$row['organic_search_visit']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```